# Table Layout with equal rows height

Tags: android

I have created a TableLayout where I want each row to have the same height, regardless of it's content.
**How can I do this?**

Here is my code. Each row element get the same width, but the heights are not equal. What am I doing wrong?

```
 <TableLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"                    android:background="@color/grey"
                android:padding="1dip" >

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@color/grey" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dip"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@color/white"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
                            android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:background="@color/white"
                            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:text="@string/car_make"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/carMake"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="1dip"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:background="@color/white"
                            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:text="@string/car_detail" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dip"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@color/white"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
                            android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:background="@color/white"
                            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:text="@string/car_model"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/carModel"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:background="@color/white"
                            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:text="@string/car_detail" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dip"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@color/white"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
                            android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:background="@color/white"
                            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:text="@string/car_version"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/carYear"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:background="@color/white"
                            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:text="@string/car_year" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@color/grey" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dip"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@color/white"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
                            android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
                            android:background="@color/white"
                                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:text="@string/car_year"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/carYear"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:background="@color/white"
                            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:text="@string/car_year" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dip"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@color/white"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
                            android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
                            android:background="@color/white"
                            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:text="@string/car_mileage"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/carYear"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:background="@color/white"
                            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:text="@string/car_year" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dip"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@color/white"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
                            android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
                            android:background="@color/white"
                            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:text="@string/car_engine_capacity"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/carYear"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:background="@color/white"
                            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:text="@string/car_year" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@color/grey" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dip"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@color/white"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
                            android:background="@color/white"
                            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:text="@string/car_engine_type"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/carYear"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:background="@color/white"
                            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:text="@string/car_year" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dip"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@color/white"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
                            android:background="@color/white"
                            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:text="@string/car_exterior_color"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/carYear"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:background="@color/white"
                            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:text="@string/car_year" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dip"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@color/white"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
                            android:background="@color/white"
                            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:text="@string/car_city"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/carYear"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:background="@color/white"
                            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:text="@string/car_year" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@color/grey" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dip"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@color/white"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
                            android:background="@color/white"
                            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:text="@string/car_transmittion"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/carYear"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:background="@color/white"
                            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:text="@string/car_year" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dip"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@color/white"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
                            android:background="@color/white"
                            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:text="@string/car_area"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/carYear"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:background="@color/white"
                            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:text="@string/car_year" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dip"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@color/white"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
                            android:background="@color/white"
                            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:text="@string/car_registered_city"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/carYear"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:background="@color/white"
                            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:text="@string/car_year" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Below Answer Deprecated Now :

You can Change in your TableRow **->** LinearLayout

```
<LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >
```

Comment: That's not what he asked. And even if that worked for him this isn't a solution of how to do a TableView with equal heights.

Answer (score 11):

Introduced in API 11, you can set `android:measureWithLargestChild="true"` on the `TableLayout` and `android:layout_weight="1"` on each `TableRow`.

Comment: didn't work, they ar rendered as in as wrap_content

Comment: nevermind, i was using TableRow.LayoutParams instead of TableLayout.LayoutParams

Answer (score 4):

here is your solution :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="4" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#B0B0B0" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#B0B0B0" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#B0B0B0" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#B0B0B0" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="4" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#B0B0B0" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#B0B0B0" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#B0B0B0" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#B0B0B0" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="4" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#B0B0B0" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#B0B0B0" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#B0B0B0" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#B0B0B0" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="4" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#B0B0B0" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#B0B0B0" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#B0B0B0" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#B0B0B0" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="4" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#B0B0B0" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#B0B0B0" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#B0B0B0" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#B0B0B0" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="4" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#B0B0B0" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#B0B0B0" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#B0B0B0" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#B0B0B0" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: How can i use if there are LineraLayouts in each column

Comment: hey what's the problem can you please elaborate.... what you wants to do .... you can do anything with linearlayouts

Comment: ok ok i understand .... you want each textview under linearlayout or there is something more ....

Answer (score 3):

here is a solution:

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

       <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        />
       <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

       <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        />
       <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        />
    </TableRow>
```

Comment: code only answers are often considered of poorer quality. You should consider leaving some explanation as to *what* you changed and *why* it should work to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this issue and solved it.
It turns out Sunny's answer worked for me.

Though as mentioned in the comment, I could figure out if it works by just reading it. I am a newbee so cannot neither leave comment nor vote it to useful. Therefore I am posting it here.

The idea is that you let `TableRow` to decide the height of the row. By setting `layout_height` to `wrap_content`, the height of the row is depends on the contents which is `TextView`.

Since the border line of the cell would be the boundary of  `TextView`, the `layout_height` should be `match_parent`.

I wish it is helpful for Android newbee (yes i am new to android too).

Answer (score -2):

```
<TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="xxdip"  // HERE define a fixed size
```

Comment: Nopes doesnt work. The height seems to be fixed. What is wrong here ?

Comment: <TableRow/> doesn't allow for changing layout_height. It's fixed by the system to always be WRAP_CONTENT