# Android: How to equally divide the table layout height to table rows in programmatically

Tags: java, android

I am creating tablerow (9 rows) dynamically. I want to equally divide the table layout height to table rows. But its not working...

I am creating 9 rows each row contains 9 TextView

My xml is

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"                                 
            android:orientation="vertical"  
            android:weightSum="100"   >

    <TableLayout 
        android:layout_weight="80"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#000"
        android:paddingTop="1dp"
        android:paddingLeft="1dp"
        android:paddingRight="1dp"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:id="@+id/sudokuboard"
        android:stretchColumns="*"
        android:weightSum="100" >

    </TableLayout>
```

And my code is

```
tblsudoku = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.sudokuboard);

    //1st Row

    for(int i=0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        TableRow NewRow1 =new TableRow(this);
        NewRow1.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,10.0f));

        NewRow1.setPadding(1, 1, 1, 1);

        for(int j=0; j<9; j++)
        {
            TextView tv_00 = new TextView(this);
            int id=10*i;
            id=id+j;
            String strText=""+id;
            tv_00.setText(strText);
            tv_00.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 10.0f));
            tv_00.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            tv_00.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
            tv_00.setId(id);
            NewRow1.addView(tv_00);
        }
        //tblsudoku.addView(NewRow1, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        tblsudoku.addView(NewRow1);

    }
```

Please help me to solve this issue...

**Updation on 29/12/2013**

New Code

```
        tblsudoku = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.sudokuboard);
    for(int i=0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        TableRow NewRow1 =new TableRow(this);
        NewRow1.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,1f));
        NewRow1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

        LinearLayout Newrowlayout =new LinearLayout(this);
        Newrowlayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1f));
        Newrowlayout.setOrientation(1);

        NewRow1.setPadding(1, 1, 1, 1);

        for(int j=0; j<9; j++)
        {
            TextView tv_00 = new TextView(this);
            int id=10*i;
            id=id+j;
            String strText=""+id;
            tv_00.setText(strText);
            tv_00.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 1f));
            tv_00.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            tv_00.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
            tv_00.setId(id);
            Newrowlayout.addView(tv_00);
        }
        NewRow1.addView(Newrowlayout);
        tblsudoku.addView(NewRow1);

    }
```

Design

```
 <TableLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"                    
            android:background="#000"
            android:paddingTop="1dp"
        android:paddingLeft="1dp"
        android:paddingRight="1dp"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
            android:id="@+id/sudokuboard">
         </TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key sentence is "A widget must have the LayoutParams of its
*parent*.", so you have to change the TableRow.LayoutParams to TableLayout.LayoutParams for your table rows.
Hope it works!

More details click [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Answers/705178/How-to-equally-divide-the-table-layout-height-to-t)

Answer (score -1):

Next time use the search bar at the top right corner before posting a question pls. Have a look at the thread below, I believe that is what your looking for.

[Table Layout with equal rows height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13738630/table-layout-with-equal-rows-height)

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I check the link but I want to create a table dynamically. I am a beginner in android please help. I also updated question with the latest code and XML.