# TextView changing its position in TableLayout

Tags: android, textview, size, tablelayout, tablerow

I have a TableLayout with some TableRows and TextViews in them. Whenever the text in it becomes too big or too much, the TextView changes its position in the TableRow instead of jumping into the next line, like this: [image]

Is there any way I can solve this problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39353698

Comment: Doesn't work, still the same result.

Answer (score 0):

how about rethinking your approach of the problem. I don't have much experience with a TableLayout but how about using a simple ListView or a RecyclerView instead? You can specify the layout for each row exactly and their behavior.